# JS I have a FileReader instance, I apply the listener onload, but does not work

Tags: ecmascript-6, filereader

I have a method that receives an array of Files

```
  const showCachePhotos = (arrayFiles) => {
    arrayFiles.forEach((file) => {
      console.log(file);
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event) {
        console.log("on load event")
      };
      reader.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log("on error event")
      };
      const test = FileReader.readAsText();
      console.log(test);
    });
  }
```

the `onload` and `onerror` listeners are not being triggered, and the `readAsText` method throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: FileReader.readAsText is not a function
```

A file looks like this:

```
File(3300372) {name: "1.JPG", lastModified: 1536502939165, lastModifiedDate: Sun Sep 09 2018 22:22:19 GMT+0800 (Central Indonesia Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 3300372, …}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `readAsText` from the instance of `FileReader` you created i.e. `reader` not `FileReader` itself.

```
reader.readAsText();
```

(Also, `readAsText()` is still asynchronous and doesn't return anything)

Comment: (Also, `readAsText()` is still asynchronous and doesn't return anything)